# KeyError(key) from new variable assigned to dataframe

Tags: python, assign

The rates data frame I read from a csv file:

```
rates = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SOMA/SomaFinal.csv',
                usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3], skiprows=6, parse_dates=['Date'])
date = rates.loc[:, "Date"]
ff = rates.loc[:, "FF"]
res  = rates.loc[:, "WRESBAL"]
iorb = rates.loc[:, "IORB"]
```

I want to create a percent change in the variable `ff` (the Fed Funds rate) and add to dataframe rates:

```
rates.assign(volf=(ff-ff.shift(1))/ff.shift(1))
vol = rates.loc[:, "volf"]
```

I get the error:

```
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'volf'
```

When I did not add `vol=reates.loc` statement, I got a name error that `vol` was not defined

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) doesn't change inplace

```py
rates = rates.assign(volf=(ff-ff.shift(1))/ff.shift(1))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do `rates["volf"] = (ff-ff.shift(1)) / ff.shift(1)`?

Comment: @wjandrea OP is confused why `assign` doesn't work.

Comment: But why use `assign` in the first place?

Comment: @wjandrea `assign` can chain operation in one expression.

Comment: But it's not being used in a chain here...

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, I don't know what OP want to do, I just solve his puzzlement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a specific reason for why `assign` needs to be used. How about:

```
rates['volf'] = (ff-ff.shift(1)) / ff.shift(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem down.  And thank you for the detailed explanations .  But now I get error: raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'ff'

Comment: Actualll it was my mistake, please try now with the edited answer

Comment: I tried two versions:    ates['volf'] = ((rates['FF']-rates['FF'].shift(1)) /    
 rates['FF'].shift(1))      
rates['volf'] = (ff-ff.shift(1)) / ff.shift(1)        
rates.loc[volf]  Now get error that volf is not defined.

Comment: Grumble: I did these plots in Matlab in 15 minutes.  But in Python, a month

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
volf = (rates.FF-rates.FF.shift(1))/rates.FF.shift(1)    
rates["volf"]=volf
```